# Headless Chrome: WebDriverException: cannot process extension #1

Tags: python, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

Running Jenkins tests using Headless Chrome with python.

I started getting this error as below:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot process extension
>
> ## 1

NO issues when running locally (Mac OS X)

Answer (score 0):

I also get this issue just update the `chromedriver` from this link

**https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/**